# Rails: Dir.mkdir not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mkdir, dir

I'm trying to create a new folder in the public folder through the console in production.

I'm running this:

```
irb(main):018:0> dir = "#{Rails.public_path}/new_dir"
=> "/app/public/new_dir"

irb(main):021:0> Dir.exists?(dir)
=> false

irb(main):022:0> Dir.mkdir(dir)
=> 0

irb(main):023:0> Dir.exists?(dir)
=> true
```

However, when I close the console on production and run it again, it says the /app/public/new_dir doesn't exist.

Any idea what's going on? and how can I really create a new folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you positive it doesn't exist? I see that the value for `dir` is `"/app/public/new_dir"`.  Note the leading slash which suggests it start at the root of your filesystem instead of `"app/public/new_dir"` which would be a path relative to your application.

Comment: I suppose you are doing this on heroku. But heroku does not allow to make such manipulations. If so, see more details here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem